# How to stream-filtering PHP’s standard output data?

Tags: php, filtering, outputstream

Is it possible to filter the data of PHP’s standard output in a stream-like fashion:

```
standard output  ⟶  output filter  ⟶  standard output
```

I’m already aware of `ob_start`. But I don’t want to process the whole output at once but in a stream-like fashion using [*php_user_filter*](http://www.php.net/~helly/classbrowser/class.php?class=php_user_filter) or something similar.

Comment: So what you have in mind is defining a callback that modifies what goes into standard output? If yes, when would that callback be called (how often)?

Comment: @Jon: The number of calls could depend on the number of output chunks (e.g. `echo` parameters, lines of output, or some internal buffer, etc.). Or it is just called once and there is a stream state that can be checked during a quasi infinite loop that processes each chunk.

Answer (score 4):

I don't quite understand what this is for, but that's no reason not to post an answer.

You can use an `ob_start()` callback and have it process **partial** content. All you have to do is set `ob_implicit_flush()` right after initialising. Now usually the callback is a simple in-out function, but you can make it as complex as desired with:

```
class ob_callback {
    function __invoke($part, $end_flag_0x04) {
        return "+$part";
        // or map to $stream->filter($in, $out, &$consumed, $closing)
    }
    function __destruct() { /* cleanup */ }
}

ob_start(new ob_callback, 2);
ob_implicit_flush(TRUE);
```

I'm not sure what a stream-y use would look like. But I think there's no other way to intercept PHP standard output. Note that the implicit flush won't work on CLI.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the second argument to `ob_start()`, `$chunk_size` for this.

`ob_start('my_callback', 1024);`

The above example would call `my_callback()` each time output causes the buffer to reach or exceed one kilobyte.  If you're spitting out several kilobytes in separate statements, `my_callback()` would be triggered several times.  This wouldn't be useful if you were outputting several kilobytes as a single string, since at most `my_callback()` can only be triggered once per output.